# NVIDIA drivers black screen on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, 19.10

I am have issues on Ubuntu 19.10 with my NVIDIA Geforce 310 card using `nvidia-340` drivers.

I installed Ubuntu from USB with "install third-party graphics" option (with auto-login turned off), immediately when the computer restarted, I got the login screen and after login just a black screen. From this point I am unable to do anything (not even opening another TTY) and I have to manually restart the system. I can however after restarting, open TTY2 and login (using ctrl+alt+f2) and then I did `sudo apt remove nvidia*` and I am able to restart and use the computer with Nouveau drivers.

I have tried uncommenting `#WaylandEnable = false` and I ensured that it is running Gnome with Xorg. If I try and do `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` at any point to reinstall `nvidia-340` drivers, I get a black screen on reboot again and the only solution is to go back to TTY2 and remove the drivers. Installing the drivers manually using the run file from nvidia website fails.

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in BIOS.

Comment: It is an old desktop pc without secure boot - `sudo mokutil --sb-state` returns `This system doesn't support Secure Boot`